# How to click button and delete input text with Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, button, xpath

I'm able to navigate this page [here][1] and enter this website [here][2](TOKEN CREATED FOR EACH DEMO FOR THIS LINK)

I'm also able to extract the value from the round count using this **xpath** here `@class,'coefficient'`

I can locate the input element on the left hand side but only one text value is deleted. I want to delete all values and enter 50.

It also seems like I can locate the left hand side button because I'm not getting any exceptions or errors but the button is not clickable.

Comment: last line you are missing `driver`

Comment: @cruisepandey noted

Comment: What exactly you want to do once you are at https://www.spribe.co/games/aviator

Comment: Click the 'DEMO' button (which I'm able to do) and go to the aviator game website, then remove the default '1.00' input text values and input my values and then click the bet button. If you copy and paste my code to your IDE it will do just that that. Only the last two part I'm having problems with.

Comment: See below and let me know if it works for you as well or not.

Answer (score 0):

The below two lines:

```
    firstInput.sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL + "a");
    firstInput.sendKeys(Keys.DELETE);
```

is basically to clear the input field, since `.clear()` is not working as expected in this case, we'd have to do `CTRL+a and then delete`

A full code will look like this:

```
driver.manage().window().maximize();
    
driver.get("https://www.spribe.co/games/aviator");
    
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
    
try {
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),' Got it')]"))).click();
    }
catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Play Demo ')]"))).click();
String originalWinHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Yes')]"))).click();
List<String> allHandles = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles());
driver.switchTo().window(allHandles.get(1));
    
WebElement firstInput = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//label[text()='BET']/ancestor::div[contains(@class,'feature')]/descendant::input")));
firstInput.sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL + "a");
firstInput.sendKeys(Keys.DELETE);
firstInput.sendKeys("20");
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//label[text()='BET']/.."))).click();
```

Comment: I tried firstInput.sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL + "a");
firstInput.sendKeys(Keys.DELETE); but not working, my input is added at the end of the default input like 1.0020. When I use firstInput.click(); firstInput.clear(); the default input is not cleared and my input is added like 1.2000. The button is not clickable again. I'm also experimenting with javascript executor but no success.

Comment: Maybe button label is not clickable because there are two buttons with BET label. I'm still busy trying to figure it out.

Comment: I managed to locate the button and click it, only the input I'm having problems with.